# How to Convert String Data to Data Table in C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So far I have tried to convert `DataTable` to `String` as follow:-

```
public static string convertDataTableToString(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        string data = string.Empty;
        int rowsCount = dataTable.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = dataTable.Rows[i];
            int columnsCount = dataTable.Columns.Count;
            for (int j = 0; j < columnsCount; j++)
            {
                data += dataTable.Columns[j].ColumnName + "~" + row[j];
                if (j == columnsCount - 1)
                {
                    if (i != (rowsCount - 1))
                        data += "$";
                }
                else
                    data += "|";
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Now I want to convert returned string into `DataTable` again.

Comment: Classic but, did you tried _anything_?

Comment: Why not use XML?  `DataTable` already has conversion methods to/from XML.

Comment: @D Stanley I have to encrypt string and than decrpty it in other application and convert it into data table

Comment: @Soner Gönül I am trying but always getting different results.

Comment: Comment for Down Vote please ?

Comment: If you have control on both applications (sender and receiver) then I agree with @D Stanley, convert to XML (or JSON if you want to look into that route) is a better solution since you can do it with less work and less chance for conversion issues. You can then encrypt the XML as seen fit and decrypt it on the receiving end as well.

Comment: @D Stanley agreed I have changed my code to convert into string format XML. Works great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String.Split` to break your string into rows and cells. If the column setup is always the same (as it should be), then you can simply add the columns on your first iteration through the cells.

Here's a simple example:

```
public static DataTable convertStringToDataTable(string data)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    bool columnsAdded = false;
    foreach(string row in data.Split('$'))
    {
        DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        foreach(string cell in row.Split('|'))
        {
            string[] keyValue = cell.Split('~');
            if (!columnsAdded)
            {
                DataColumn dataColumn = new DataColumn(keyValue[0]);
                dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
            }
            dataRow[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
        }
        columnsAdded = true;
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

Alternatively you could get a list of all columns prior to the loop, but this way is likely easier for your purpose.